# How to calculate how many times a string appears in another string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, substring, infix-notation

I need to find out for example how many times *test* appears in *ttest* and answer for that would be 2, or for example *world* in *w1o1r1l1d* and answer would be one. I have already written a code which finds all possibilities, and then checks if it is the string I am searching for, but that is too slow.

Comment: Did you check any of those? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_searching_algorithm

Comment: Could you please share your code and how did you measure that it is too slow..

Comment: Without seeing your code, no one can tell how to improve it ...

Comment: Which language did you choose to implement this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032730/can-you-help-me-make-this-program-faster here is my complete code in pascal, but no one helped me :\

Comment: Just because no one answered your question the first time doesn't mean you should post it again.

Comment: Search for index of first occurrence of the string, then resume at the index + string length until another occurrence, and so on until the end, while counting.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try a recursive solution.

The number of times a one-letter string appears in another string is the number of times that characters appears there.

```
the number of time "r" appears in "program" is 2
```

The number of times a n-letter string appears in another string is:
the number of times the (n-1)- string appears after the first match for the first letter   plus the number of times the n-letter string appears after the first match

```
the number of times "test" appears in "ttest" is
      the number of times "est" appears in "test"
    + the number of times "test" appears in "test"
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int count(const char *needle, const char *stack) {
  int n = 0;
  const char *p;
  if (*stack == 0) return 0;
  if (*needle == 0) return 0;
  p = strchr(stack, *needle);
  if (needle[1] == 0) n += !!p;
  if (p) {
    n += count(needle + 1, p + 1);
    n += count(needle, p + 1);
  }
  return n;
}

int main(void) {
  const char *needle, *stack;

  needle = "a"; stack = "";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  needle = ""; stack = "a";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  needle = "a"; stack = "abracadabra";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  needle = "br"; stack = "abracadabra";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  needle = "test"; stack = "ttest";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  needle = "world"; stack = "w1o1r1l1d";
  printf("[%s] exists %d times in [%s]\n", needle, count(needle, stack), stack);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can see the code "running" at codepad.org: http://codepad.org/Jktgdbp7